# HOW TO modify a google spreadsheet from collaborators that aren't editors?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-apps

I have a master and a client google spreadsheet
Client is a copy of the master
I only can access in master ss, my collaborator only in the client ss. My collaborator can edit the client ss; then clicking a menu (called "register") should write his modifications on the Master ss and send me automatically a mail.

Ok, all is ok if my collaborator is a editor on the master; otherwise the register script doesn't go.

How can I do? I have looked for this and I have seen that there is an AddEditor method but I don't know use.

var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SS.KEY')

here there is an error; You don't have permissions...

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use a web app. i.e. create a web app for the master spreadsheet using your account. You can trigger the web app from a URL and even pass parameters.
Setup the client spreadsheet with a script that is able to call the web app.

The webapp will run "As you", with all your rights. The client script will run as the person editing the client spreadsheet.

Comment: +1 I use this method frequently.  I originally realised what to do after seeing the following, which might also help @ulisse:  http://www.jellybend.com/2012/12/18/trigger-updates-between-master-slave-spreadsheets/

Comment: thank you i have resolved with the triggers, but i have problem with the access to the code...