# How to allow a user to write to a spreadsheet without sharing the file being written to

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want the user to be able to write information to a master sheet. I'm able to get the user to write to it by sharing the master sheet. However, I don't want them to really have access to view it. Is there any work-around this?

```html
function writeRecords(currentSheet) {
  // get current sheet
  var currentLastRow = currentSheet.getLastRow();
  var currentRange = currentSheet.getRange(2, 1, currentLastRow, 6);
  var currentValues = currentRange.getValues();
  // get master sheet
  var masterSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("fakesheetid")
  var masterSheet = masterSpreadSheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var masterLastRow = masterSheet.getLastRow();
  
  // need to insert into master spreadsheet startin from its last row
  masterSheet.getRange((masterLastRow + 1), 1, currentLastRow, 6).setValues(currentValues);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HOW TO modify a google spreadsheet from collaborators that aren't editors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16276969/how-to-modify-a-google-spreadsheet-from-collaborators-that-arent-editors)

Answer (score 1):

Create a web app that run as you.

Related

- [HOW TO modify a google spreadsheet from collaborators that aren't editors?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16276969/1595451)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should consider using [Google Forms](https://docs.google.com/forms/u/0/)?

Google Forms allows you to set up an interface to gather information from a user and use a Google Sheet as the repository for which this information is dumped into.